# Using SSL over an Iridium connection

Tags: ssl, satellite

I am using an Iridium (satellite constellation) modem to exchange information any where in the world. The main goal is to send messages over Internet.
Those messages might include confidential information and I was wondering what the possible ways are to secure the line.I thought about SSL.

The bandwidth of iridium is estimated at 0.3kb/s (300 **bytes** / sec).

**Q:** Will this solution (SSL) be viable with such a slow bandwidth ?

I know the handshake (SSL setup) includes lots of data (~5kb) but this is not a problem to wait 1 minute to have the connection established. My question refers to the next step, when it comes to send the messages, will it cause a major slowdown in the exchanges ?.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption should not really cause a slowdown.

If you are using SMTP to send the messge, check whether the SMTP server accepts secure connections. Most e-mail clients can connect to a SMTP server via SSL/TLS encrypted SMTP (it uses port 465).

If you worry about the contents of the email itself, then encrytion before sending it is advised IMHO. See e.g. https://guardianproject.info/code/gnupg/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a good thing if encryption will not cause a slowndown. About the messages, it won't be emails but more like chat messages that will be sent between an iridium phone directly to a computer connected to internet or another iridium phone. Therefore SMTP protocol can't be use here. Do you have any idea about the overhead that will add SSL or any other encryption protocol ?

Comment: Overhead numbers require testing.                                                            If the chat server accepts TLS sessions, you only need to configure your chat client. Otherwise, the chat server may be enhanced with [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html). Stunnel is a proxy designed to add TLS encryption functionality to existing clients and servers without any changes in the programs' code. It helped me in the past to get access to a system in the office. To know whether your chat client supports TLS I would need to know more about the differnet pieces you want to work with.

Comment: Encryption of messages usually works in ASCII. If your message client supports compression, the overhead should be low.